# Custom icon markers sometimes are not working from MapBox-GL in React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-native-mapbox-gl

I'm trying to edit the map markers to look like the image below:

[image]

And here is my code to create markers:

```
const MapBoxComponent = () => {
    const [markers] = useState([
        {
            title: 'hello',
            coordinates: [108.24065199465605, 16.049580619790696]
        },
        {
            title: 'hello',
            coordinates: [108.24177161264663, 16.051053734988322]
        },
        {
            title: 'hello',
            coordinates: [108.23945068795894, 16.05118303611558]
        },
        {
            title: 'hello',
            coordinates: [108.24056069541828, 16.05149705278938]
        },
        {
            title: 'hello',
            coordinates: [108.24175239173825, 16.051012173893877]
        },
        {
            title: 'hello',
            coordinates: [108.24081537245439, 16.050171714344984]
        }
    ]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapboxGL.MapView
                style={styles.map}
                styleURL={MapboxGL.StyleURL.Outdoors}
            >
                <MapboxGL.Camera
                    zoomLevel={15}
                    centerCoordinate={markers[2].coordinates}
                />

                {markers.map((marker) => (
                    <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                        id={marker.title}
                        children={true}
                        coordinate={marker.coordinates}
                        title={marker.title}
                    >
                        {/* <View
                            style={{
                                height: 30,
                                width: 30,
                                backgroundColor: 'red',
                                borderRadius: 50,
                                borderColor: '#fff',
                                borderWidth: 3
                            }}
                        /> */}
                         <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
                            id="pointCount"
                            style={layerStyles.icon}
                        /> 
                    </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
                ))}
            </MapboxGL.MapView>
        </View>
    );
};

export default MapBoxComponent;
```

And Style for MapBox custom:

```
const layerStyles = {
    icon: {
        iconAllowOverlap: true,
        iconIgnorePlacement: true,
        iconSize: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 1 : 0.5,
        iconOffset: [0, 5],
        textField: '2%',
        textSize: 14
    },
    iconPremium: {
        textColor: '#fff',
        textHaloColor: '#fff',
        textHaloWidth: 0.3
    },
    iconPremiumSelected: {
        textColor: '#D7B218',
        textHaloColor: '#D7B218',
        textHaloWidth: 0.1
    },
    clusterCount: {
        textField: '0',
        textSize: 18,
        textHaloColor: '#fff',
        textHaloWidth: 0.3,
        textColor: '#fff'
    }
};
```

So I am having the same problem that after i run on android my markers are not showing on the map, but when I remove this code in the previous code the markers are back is displayed.

```
<MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
   id="pointCount"
   style={layerStyles.icon}
   />
```

So can anyone here help me to explain and solve this problem, Thank you

The library that I use above is learned from here:
https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps